# Styling drawer in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

here is my drawer SS
[drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idly7.png)

i want to change text color and text background when a screen is selected in drawer. I have tried activeTintColor and activeBackgroundColor but they don't work. and i want to change drawer backgroundColor in two different colors. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using React Navigation. I recommend you to use a custom component instead. Take a look to related docs:

[drawerContent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent)

Answer (score 0):

For `React-Navigation` V6:

```
<MyDrawers.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{ 
    drawerActiveTintColor: "red",
    drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "yellow", 
  }}
>
   <MyDrawers.Screen name="TestingStack" component={TestingStack}/>
</MyDrawers.Navigator>
```